# Conditionally Validate fields on VF page

Tags: trigger, controller-extension, visualforce

Here is what I need, I have 12 * 3 (36)  number fields named after each Month(Jan,feb,march...etc,.) on the VF page for 3 years 2016, 2017 and 2018.

Now, if my start date is Jan 2016  and end date is April 2016 I should be allowed to enter values only in the months: January, February, March and April for year 2016 and rest fields should be locked from editing or should populate with an error.

Please see the screen shot below:
[image]

Comment: Hi Naz, welcome to SFSE! Please visit the [help] and read [ask]. If you include the code you have so far, it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: Please post your VF page and controller so that we can have a better clarity

Comment: I am unable to post complete code here. However, I've refrenced the code provided in the link below with both vf and controller:  http://crawlapexnvisualforce.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/salesforce-opportunity-product-extension.html

Comment: @AdrianLarson any updates?